# How to read Property pages from visual studio addin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties, biztalk, add-in

I'm working on a visual studio add-in to debug BizTalk maps using external objects. I have a roadblock to read existing property page for BizTalk map files (.btm properties). I was able to read file configuration by reading the file. However I'm not sure how to read property pages. I'm looking for values of TestMap Input Instance and TestMap Output instance. I tried this, however buildPropertyStorage is null.

```
ProjectItem projectItem = _applicationObject.SelectedItems.Item(1).ProjectItem;
string name = "Name";

IVsHierarchy hierarchy;

Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider sp = (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider)_applicationObject;

IntPtr ip;
Guid id1, id2;
id1 = id2 = typeof(SVsSolution).GUID;
int hr = sp.QueryService(ref id1, ref id2, out ip);

IVsSolution solution = (IVsSolution)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(ip);

solution.GetProjectOfUniqueName(projectItem.ContainingProject.UniqueName, out hierarchy);
IVsBuildPropertyStorage buildPropertyStorage = hierarchy as IVsBuildPropertyStorage;

string value = null;
if (buildPropertyStorage != null)
{
       uint itemId;
       string fullPath = (string)projectItem.Properties.Item("FullPath").Value;
       hierarchy.ParseCanonicalName(fullPath, out itemId);

       buildPropertyStorage.GetItemAttribute(itemId, name, out value);
}
```